# How can i replace a db name using variable in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can use variables for query filtering conditions. E.g.,

```
set mytime = '2021-12-12 09:00:00';

select col1
from db1.schema.table1
where event_time > $mytime
```

However, if I use the same way to replace the db1 with a variable, it will not work. I.e.,

```
set mytime = '2021-12-12 09:00:00';
set db_name = 'db1';

select col1
from $db_name.schema.table1
where event_time > $mytime
```

Comment: You might not be able to use it directly, but you can do use database identifier($db_name) and then select query excluding dbname qualifier, like select colname from schema_name.table;

Comment: See the session variable section of https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html#examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if your variable has a fully qualified name db/schema/table name and you use the [IDENTIFIER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html) function can help.

```
create table test.test.db1(id number);

set db_name = 'test.test.db1';

insert into test.test.db1 values (1),(2),(3);
```

then this works:

```
select id
from identifier ($db_name);
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

but composing the string on the fly does not presently work:

```
select id
from identifier ($just_db_name||'.test.db1');
```

but you can two step this:

```
set fqn_db_name = $just_db_name||'.test.db1';

select id
from identifier ($fqn_db_name);
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

### Snowflake Scripting:

Using [snowflake scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html), it can be done as a single "statement", like so:

```
begin
    let fqn text := $just_db_name || '.test.db1';
    let res resultset := (select id from identifier(:fqn));
    return table(res);
end;
```

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |